# Passing integer array from Unmanaged to Managed code via COM

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, com, interop

I have a `DLL` in `C#`, which accepts an integer array as an argument, and returns another.
This`DLL` is loaded by an `unmanaged` application through `CO`M.

However, I am not able to pass an integer array from `C++` to `C#` via `COM`. The function signature converts the input integer array to `long`, and the return parameter to `long` as well, just variables, not `pointers`.

I have a feeling I am overlooking something fundamental here, but being new to `COM`, I am not able to figure out why it happens so.

Comment: Arrays should be passed as a SAFEARRAY.  How you got `long` defies any reasonable guess, a `ref int` is the usual mishap when you try to pass int*.  Use SAFEARRAY.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For some weird reason, the tooltip when I hover over the function still shows `long` in `VS`. I have managed to send the `SAFERRAY` over to the managed `DLL`, and it works fine. How do i receive a `SAFEARRAY` from the `DLL` into `Unmanaged `code?